# Python Selenium Xpath get text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation

Please how I can find the text `Invalid email address.` inside  this xpath:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='create_account_error']/ol/li")
```

and verify with assert?

You can check this website - http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication

Put in a wrong email address in "CREATE AN ACCOUNT tab" and click "Create an account", and you will see an error message.

How can I verify this error message with xpath to make a sample test case?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please, read the guidelines for posting questions on SO carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this:

```
expected_text = 'Invalid email address.'
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='create_account_error']/ol/li")
assert elem.text == expected_text
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you sample code which will work what you want, put it in a testcase accordingly .

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication"

driver =webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element(By.ID,'email_create').send_keys("This is Test")

driver.find_element(By.ID,'SubmitCreate').click()

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#create_account_error > ol > li")))

ele=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#create_account_error > ol > li')
assert ele.text == 'Invalid email address.'

driver.quit()
```